# Vertical alignment of an Android SwitchCompat?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, switchcompat

In Android, is it possible to vertical align a SwitchCompat , that is, to put the text above the switch instead of on the left of the switch ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you looking for something like this ..?

[image]

try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/switchLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/switchTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Switch"/>
    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/switch1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't need to rotate the switch but  I'll remember it for next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt look like it.
U can wrap a TextView and SwitchCompat with a LinearLayout to get the result that u want.